# bash - how to pipe result from the which command to cd

Tags: linux, bash, shell, cd

How could I pipe the result from a `which` command to `cd`?

This is what I am trying to do:

```
which oracle | cd
cd < which oracle
```

But none of them works.

Is there a way to achieve this (rather than copy/paste of course)?

**Edit : on second thought, this command would fail, because the destination file is NOT a folder/directory**.

So I am thinking and working out a better way to get rid of the trailing "/oracle" part now (sed or awk, or even Perl) :)

**Edit :
Okay that's what I've got in the end:**

```
cd `which oracle | sed 's/\/oracle//g'`
```

Comment: which gives you command, not directory

Comment: are you trying to get directory where program is installed? `dirname`, `basename `?

Comment: @aaa : you are right, I think dirname is better because it points to "the real dir" not a symbolic link to the oracle executable...which is why my sed apporach would fail :)

Answer (score 160, accepted):

You use pipe in cases where the command expects parameters from the standard input. ( [More on this](https://superuser.com/a/178798/320348) ).

With `cd` command that is not the case. The directory is the command argument. In such case, you can use command substitution. Use backticks or `$(...)` to evaluate the command, store it into variable..

```
path=`which oracle`
echo $path # just for debug
cd $path
```

although it can be done in a much simpler way:

```
cd `which oracle`
```

or if your path has special characters

```
cd "`which oracle`"
```

or

```
cd $(which oracle)
```

which is equivalent to backtick notation, but is recommended (backticks can be confused with apostrophes)

.. but it looks like you want:

```
cd $(dirname $(which oracle))
```

(which shows you that you can use nesting easily)

`$(...)` (as well as backticks) work also in double-quoted strings, which helps when the result may eventually contain spaces..

```
cd "$(dirname "$(which oracle)")"
```

(Note that both outputs require a set of double quotes.)

Comment: Cool. Could you please explain a bit about what is going on here? That looks like a variable dereference; is there some default temporary variable where the results of a command go?

Comment: Ahhh, I forgot compelete about the backticks :(

Comment: You need another pair of quotes: `cd "$(dirname "$(which oracle)")"`.

Comment: The `|` opens a new process, so even if `cd` read from STDIN, `cmd | cd` wouldn't work (i.e. the current directory in the original process would remain the same).

Answer (score 27):

With dirname to get the directory:

```
cd $(which oracle | xargs dirname)
```

---

EDIT: beware of paths containing spaces, see @anishpatel comment below

Comment: Use `cd "$(which oracle | xargs -0 dirname)"` if the path may contain whitespace. The -0 flag splits input by null rather than whitespace.

Answer (score 12):

```
cd `which oracle`
```

Note those are backticks (generally the key to the left of 1 on a US keyboard)

Comment: This doesn't work if the path contains spaces or other "special" characters, and you have to strip off the file name.

Comment: @Philipp you can use this if your path has special characters `cd "\`which oracle\`"`

Answer (score 4):

OK, here a solution that uses correct quoting:

```
cd "$(dirname "$(which oracle)")"
```

Avoid backticks, they are less readable, and always quote process substitutions.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a pipe, you can do what you want using Bash parameter expansion!

Further tip: use "type -P" instead of the external "which" command if you are using Bash.

```
# test
touch /ls
chmod +x /ls
cmd='ls'
PATH=/:$PATH
if cmdpath="$(type -P "$cmd")" && cmdpath="${cmdpath%/*}" ; then
   cd "${cmdpath:-/}" || { echo "Could not cd to: ${cmdpath:-/}"; exit 1; }
else
   echo "No such program in PATH search directories: ${cmd}"
   exit 1
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

besides good answer above, one thing needs to mention is that **cd** is a shell builtin, which run in the same process other than new process like **ls** which is a command.

1. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/50022/why-cant-i-redirect-a-path-name-output-from-one-command-to-cd
2. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_builtin

Answer (score 1):

In response to your edited question, you can strip off the name of the command using `dirname`:

```
cd $(dirname `which oracle`)
```

Comment: This doesn't work if the path contains spaces or other "special" characters.

Comment: Easily fixed by double-quoting it.