# Calling node.js script from PHP returns nothing

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, apache

What I want to do is simple in theory, but I cannot quite get it to work.

I wrote a simple node.js script that uses the `request` package to asynchronously fetch some data, parse it, and spit it out as html. I wanted to integrate this script in my client's php and apache based website which is on a shared host, and ran into some snags:

1. There is no mod_proxy, so I can't simply run my node script as a server and proxy through Apache
2. I don't want to run node on port 80 and proxy to apache from node. It's just way too much overkill for what I need to do, and would introduce too many headaches for me. My particular shared host is known to have trouble keeping node server instances up, and I can't justify potential downtime just for this script to run.
3. I tried the `node-cgi` package but it didn't work for me. I got errors about internal node methods not existing, I think this package is just out of date.

So what I have landed on is trying to simply call node from PHP. My whole `index.php` file is:

```
<?php
  header("Content-Type: text/html");
  exec("node beerlist.nd", $output);
  echo implode('', $output);
```

When I execute `php index.php` on the command line, I get my expected output, however, when I try to access this from the browser, I get nothing ie `Content-Length: 0`. Why?

I thought maybe it had to do with the async nature of my node script but it seems like the process stays alive until it finishes all the async calls. So shouldn't my php snippet send the output to the browser without any trouble? What am I missing here?

Edit: This gist of my node script is

```
var req = require('request')

req("http://mywebsite.com", function(err, resp, body) {
  var output = // pull some interesting pieces out of the whole body
  console.log(output);
});
```

The generation of my `output` variable is not central to the issue here. The relevant parts are that I use `request` to make an asynchronous call and use `console.log` to output my results... maybe this is a problem?

Comment: Does exec'ing `node beerlist.nd` yield a non-empty result?

Comment: If you mean doing `node beerlist.nd` on the command line, yes, it is non-empty.

Comment: Well you are mixing two different technologies, wouldn't that be easier if your node program makes parsing and then over the http you get the results back ? This seems to be really hack solution and should be avoided.

Comment: @jurka true, but I wrote the node script to work on a full node stack, and then wanted to use it on another apache/php site. This was the path of least resistance, and ended up working out just fine for me.

Comment: FWIW, "lots of regexing and string functions on body" sets off alarm bells in my head.  If you're dealing with HTML, you should use [a proper parser](https://github.com/MatthewMueller/cheerio), because [regexes aren't the right way to deal with HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/201952).

Comment: ...also, you probably should write directly to [`process.stdout`](http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_stdout) instead of using `console.log`.

Comment: `console.log` writes to stdout after minimal formatting http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4976466/difference-between-process-stdout-write-and-console-log-in-node-js... also, my string functions simply strip out white space and a few unwanted lines. The accepted answer worked for me.

Comment: sry, I did leave out that I used the `cheerio` library to extract the HTML that I needed, the regex was just to remove whitespace

Comment: also, I agree with what you said aout regexs not bein the "right" way to deal with HTML but what i needed in my case was super simple, and I don't think my regex was very unclear. (Besides, regex should be used ONCE in a while despite how confusing it may be)

Comment: whether my regexes worked or not actually has nothing to do with my problem, as I stated that running the node script directly does exactly what it was supposed to do.

Comment: @parker.sikand: Yes, I know that `console.log` also goes to stdout, but *after* doing other things that you don't necessarily have control over.  It's also (marginally) slower due to the overhead of doing those things.  Finally, using `process.stdout.write` makes it crystal clear to someone reading your code that you **intend** to output data on stdout and it's not just a debugging line (which is usually what `console.log` is) that got left in the code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suppose Apache user doesn't know what `node` command is. If I'm right try to write in php file:

```
<full path to node> beerlist.nd
```

instead of

```
node beerlist.nd
```

To get full path to node run in terminal `which node`

Comment: As a note, using Bluehost shared hosting, calling an unknown executable from PHP does not yield an error line, so be careful!

Comment: Is there a way to get full path to node in php rather than in terminal? This way I won't need to update my php file every time I upgrade nodejs or push to a production server.

Comment: @smohadjer, you could try to execute this command in PHP: `"$(which node)" beerlist.nd`. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/3437514/1079869 for more info.