# Unable to execute server.js from php node js

Tags: php, node.js

I am unable to execute the node server.js file from php code but when I executes it from terminal it works fine.

```
<?php exec('/usr/local/bin/node Sever.js'); ?>
```

Comment: Can you switch on your verbose please ? :) We need more informations about "why do you say it doesn't work", there are so many possible way a thing doesn't work...

Comment: In my project I have a Server.js file which includes node.js libraries. So when I execute it from terminal it is executing but not from my index.php file.

Comment: how do you see it doesn't ? have you error logs ? saying it couldn't execute ? have you logs before that line to be sure the code goes up there ?

Comment: Yes the code goes up there. I've already checked that.

Comment: 2 things : 1: you got a space in your exec. 2: you should have something in your php_error if you reach that line but doesn't exec it...

Comment: You have `Sever.js` in the PHP `exec()`, but you said that the script is called Server.js?

Comment: Yes it looks like that but originally there is no space in between Server.js, I've checked it twice.

Comment: 1) So, `Sever.js` or `Server.js`? 2) Check that the php file and 'sever.js` (or `server.js`?) are in one folder, or specify the full path to the `server.js` in exec.

Comment: This is what  I did exec('node /var/www/docs/Silkeletz/public/silk_Eletz/admin/Server.js');  I gave full path to the Server.js but it's still not working.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to execute the file. First get full path to node. 
Run in terminal < which node > then add web path of your js file in exec function.

Check here [Calling node.js script from PHP returns nothing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21958942/calling-node-js-script-from-php-returns-nothing)

```
exec('/usr/local/bin/node '.WEB_PATH.'/Server.js');
```